# Logging out of Facebook with WebAuthenticationBroker

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I'm building a Windows Store 8.1 application in C#.  It's a photo booth application, so many different people are going to be walking up to a single device and getting their pictures taken.

One of the features of the application is the ability to share your photo on social media sites.  I was able to implement a Facebook login using WebAuthenticationBroker.  However, what I need to do next is post their photo and then log out of Facebook.  The last thing I want is for somebody else coming up to the photo booth with a different person's cached credentials.

I could use any advice on how to proceed here.  Below is the code I used to log in:

```
WebAuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MyAppId&response_type=token&scope=publish_actions&redirect_uri=" + WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()));
```

Through great pains I was also able to capture what the Facebook logout URL should look like:

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=MyAccessToken&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html

Has anybody figured this one out yet?

Answer (score -1):

What is your exact question? How to post photos to Facebook?

Although there is no official C# SDK by Facebook, the following might be the easiest to use: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/

Otherwise, you can implement raw API calls and POST to `{user_id}/photos`, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

When you app is live, you also need to submit for review and request the `publish_actions` and `user_photos` permissisons.